# File no found following use of Name function

Tags: vba

I am trying to do is rename a file. Here is my code. It comes back with "File not found". The directory is correct. I have double and tripled checked. The error message persists. Here is the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub RenamePictureFileName()

    Dim sPath As String
    Dim oldPrato As String, newPrato As String
    Dim oldName As String, newName As String

    oldPrato = "Migas de Couve.jpeg"
    newPrato = "Mais migas de couve.jpeg"

   sPath = "/Users/victorgameiro/Dropbox/AT Macela/Excel Databases/" & _
        "FICHAS TÉCNICAS/Fotos/Fotos FT/"

    oldName = sPath & oldPrato
    newName = sPath & newPrato
    Debug.Print oldName
    Debug.Print newName
    Name oldName As newName

End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing the drive letter.

Comment: Looks like you're on a Mac?  That's always worth mentioning since VBA tends to be windows-centric in terms of people who hang out here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the drive letter like this:

sPath = "C:/Users/victorgameiro/Dropbox/AT Macela/Excel Databases/" & _
"FICHAS TÉCNICAS/Fotos/Fotos FT/"

If it isn’t C: replace the letter to the drive the file is.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not mentioning that I am indeed working with Excel for Mac which means that the path indicated is the proper way to identify the path. There is no C:\ drive on a Mac. The path indicated in my code works fine in other uses. Given that the problem persists, is it then possible that the code does not work on the Mac version of excel?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac system does not use letters as drives. If I do add the letter for the drive it comes back with “cannot find drive”. I suspect that this function is just another of the functions that does not work on the Mac version of Excel. I have to find a way around it until such time as MS decides to fix this problem.  In the mean time I’ll test the code on a PC to see if my code works.

I appreciate the help.